# Displaying and searching Custom Posts

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-field, search

I'm trying to convert my existing web site from old-school HTML to WordPress, and have created a series of Custom Posts for my whisky tasting notes.

However, I'm stuck trying to set up a page that will let users search by the name of the whisky, region (saved as custom taxonomies) and score (0-100 scale), as well as display all three of those variables plus the ABV value (proof). Score and ABV are saved as custom metadata. The name of the whisky serves as the post title, and the tasting notes are in the text of the post.

I've tried adapting templates in the `single.php` file to make this work, but don't get any of them to display.

How to code this or a plug-in that will automate the process?